# Receive a notification when a friend appears online in Facebook chat

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-apps, facebook-messenger

Recently, I've been wondering about the possibility of receiving a notification when a friend comes online in Facebook chat.

After a bit of googling, I've found http://www.gmarjil.com/ and http://apps.facebook.com/chatalert/. However, both appear to be broken.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an instant messaging client application, such as Trillian, Pidgin, Digsby etc., you can set them up to be able to chat over Facebook too, and those programs have settings that let you play a specific notification sound when a particular friend comes online.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an Android Phone, you can use [Onliner for Facebook](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=flashbang.apps.fbtrack).

You can track your friends, and it will notify you when any of them come online.

Answer (score 1):

[buddybuzzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.oxylab.buddybuzzer) is a cool app for Android. It doesn't have too many things to confuse. Have some added features like ring notification. Simple but useful.